# How to properly replace @wdio/selenium-standalone-service service?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, wdio

**Setup / What I have done so far**

I am currently updating our project and we still use some older (@wdio@8.0.0 and up version). They have deprecated the "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service service". I read about it here:

- https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/releases/tag/v8.14.6
- https://webdriver.io/blog/2023/07/31/driver-management/

There used to be an option to configure this service:

`config.services = ['selenium-standalone'];`

Config is basically Options.Testrunner from "@wdio/types".

When I remove the dependency as well as the line above from my config, my tests run in the most recent chrome browser.

**Issue I am facing**

I have to make sure, that the local tests still run in selenium and are not executed with e.g. chromedriver. I want to make sure that there is no difference when I execute tests locally and on gitlab CI.

When I used to run the tests, it said:

`INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol`

Now it says:

```
INFO devtools:puppeteer: Initiate new session using the DevTools protocol
[0-0] 2024-02-06T16:55:36.106Z INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome (undefined) with flags: --enable-automation --disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling...
```

**Question**

How can I configure it so it still uses selenium? I want to upgrade only what is the bare minimum. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: It looks like you're currently using DevTools protocol (which is puppeteer)... maybe see here for example setup for WebDriver (which is Selenium): https://github.com/webdriverio/example-recipes/blob/e8b147e88e7a38351b0918b4f7efbd9ae292201d/setup/webdriver.js  According to this link it will first check for a compatible webdriver and if not found fallback to devtools: https://webdriver.io/docs/automationProtocols/#:~:text=By%20default%20WebdriverIO%20will%20always,using%20Puppeteer%20under%20the%20hood.

Comment: @browsermator Thanks, but that did not help much. I need selenium I must not rely on a fallback. I've tried adding the selenium-standalone to my lib instead of the @wdio/selenium-standalone-service one and I got this: "Error: Couldn't find plugin "selenium-standalone" service, neither as wdio scoped package "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service" nor as community package "wdio-selenium-standalone-service". Welp. Why is there no documentation on how to migrate this service. Maybe I just did not find it but ...

Comment: Don't know if this helps, and I've never used webdriver.io before, but I believe at some point Selenium made it so that the "-standalone" version was for grid only.  You'd just need the standard Selenium bindings + drivers for local.  It sounds like all you need is to make sure your drivers are on the machine (chromedriver, geckodriver, etc... executables) and they are in PATH environment variables, then it will default to Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by just specifying `config.services = []`. Since I removed this entry completely, it was undefined and it seems that wdio tried to run it with the fallback i.e. DevTools Protocol. It now uses the WebDriver Protocol as expected.

Also, I've learned that selenium was only used to download the drivers and it is fully integrated now, so I don't need any additional selenium server to run it locally.